# Query from a list, to return from a dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

A list and, a dictionary of dictionary, as below, and I want to do some query.

Every element in the list is a people's name and a query_date (in string format)

The dictionary has keys of people’s names, its value is a dictionary that using a announcement_date (in string format) as a key, and bonus as value.

From the list given people’s name and query_date, I want to find out the people’s bonus, that’s when the announcement_date is the closest (and earlier than) the query_date.

For example, "Mike 20191022" shall return Mike’s bonus announced in 20190630 (i.e. 105794.62).

What I have tried is, to find out the differences of every announcement_date, and compare them with the query_date. From the smallest difference, I got an index, and use the index to return the correspondent bonus.

```
import numpy as np

to_do = ["Mike 20191022"]

bonus = {'Mike': {'20200630': '105794.62', '20191231': '105794.62', '20190630': '105794.62', '20181231': '105794.62', '20180630': '95122.25', '20171231': '95122.25', '20170630': '95122.25'}}

for ox in to_do:
    to_do_people = ox.split(' ')[0]"
    to_do_date = ox.split(' ')[1]"
    for key, s_dict in bonus.items():"
        if to_do_people == key:"
            tem_list = []"
            for k, v in (s_dict.items()):"
                tem_list.append(int(to_do_date) - int(k))"
            idx = np.argmin(tem_list)"
            print (ox + '@Bonus@'  + list(s_dict.keys())[idx] + '@' + list(s_dict.values())[idx])"
```

However it doesn't work. The output is:

```
Mike 20191022@Bonus@20200630@105794.62
```

What went wrong and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should append the `abs` value.

since `min(-1000, 100, 0)` is `-1000`, but what you want is `0`.

```py
tem_list.append(abs(int(to_do_date) - int(k)))
```

which gives the output as

```
Mike 20191022@Bonus@20191231@105794.62
```

But that won't solve your problem that your result date should be before the query date. This problem can be solved easily by setting all the dates after query date a very big number.

```py
tem_list.append(abs(int(to_do_date) - int(k)) if (int(to_do_date)>=int(k)) else float('inf'))
```

What it does is, it sets `infinity` for all the dates that come after the query date.

So, the solution becomes

```py
import numpy as np

to_do = ["Mike 20191022"]

bonus = {'Mike': {'20200630': '105794.62', '20191231': '105794.62', '20190630': '105794.62', '20181231': '105794.62', '20180630': '95122.25', '20171231': '95122.25', '20170630': '95122.25'}}

for ox in to_do:
    to_do_people = ox.split(' ')[0]
    to_do_date = ox.split(' ')[1]
    for key, s_dict in bonus.items():
        if to_do_people == key:
            tem_list = []
            for k, v in (s_dict.items()):
                tem_list.append(abs(int(to_do_date) - int(k)) if (int(to_do_date)>=int(k)) else float('inf'))
            idx = np.argmin(tem_list)
            print (ox + '@Bonus@'  + list(s_dict.keys())[idx] + '@' + list(s_dict.values())[idx])
```

output

```
Mike 20191022@Bonus@20190630@105794.62
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are importing `numpy`, use [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
>>> for query in to_do:
       name, date = query.split()
       keys = sorted(map(int,bonus[name].keys()))
       ix = np.searchsorted(keys, int(date), side='right') - 1
       print(f"{name} {date}@bonus@{keys[ix]}@{bonus[name][str(keys[ix])]}")

Mike 20191022@bonus@20190630@105794.62
```

**EXPLANATION:**

```
For first iteration, query == "Mike 20191022"
>>> name, date = query.split()
>>> name
"Mike"
>>> date
"20191022"
# then we sort the keys of the dict:
>>> sorted(map(int,bonus[name].keys()))
[20170630, 20171231, 20180630, 20181231, 20190630, 20191231, 20200630]
# Now we search for the index of the first date >= query_date
>>> np.searchsorted(keys, int(date), side='right')
5
# So 5th index is first date >= query_date
# If we check, we will find: keys[5] == 20191231 > 20191022

# However, we want the date before that, so subtract 1 from index
>>> ix = np.searchsorted(keys, int(date), side='right') - 1
>>> ix
4
# Now we first get the required date:
>>> keys[ix] # == keys[4]
20190630
# And then we access the bonus:
>>> bonus[name][str(keys[ix])]
"105794.62"
```

Now we print it using [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

Comment: thank you for your help! would you mind that I choose another that gives more detail guide as the answer (yours' advanced and not every beginner can catch up. :))

Comment: Sure, it is your call, whichever you find more suitable/helpful. This one should be faster, however, I agree on the beginner friendliness part. I have provided the documentation for `numpy.searchsorted`, you can click to follow the official guide, it will help. Meanwhile, I will add some explanation.